# Move views under ScrollView on pull to refresh

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

I have a layout like on the picture bellow. On it I have:

- general header
- tabs
- table

Depending on the selected tab I display `UITableView` with different data.

[image: my simplified layout]

I need to implement pull to refresh functionality for the screen. I just didn't want to invent a bicycle and tried to use `UIScrollView`, but I can't use it as container for the whole screen, because the `UITableView` already has is own `UIScrollView`. Thus I wrapped the header into a `UIScrollView`, but when I do pull to refresh the header moves behind the tabs and the table.

[image: when I do pull to refresh]

Can anybody advise how to move views under `UIScrollView` when I do pull to refresh in the `UIScrollView`, but do not hide content of the header behind Views below? Or how put `UITableView` inside `UIScrollView` in a safe way.

Answer (score 0):

For this you can drag and drop `UIView` in UITable View Just uper the cell. Then You can use that `UIView` acording to you.

[image]